# responsive child theme and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a problem with wordpress and childify the responsive theme (from http://cyberchimps.com/).

This is the website http://www.mas-seraphin.com/la-bergerie/ but you need to overide in hosts file with  213.186.33.4       www.mas-seraphin.com

This my css file for the child theme:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Responsive Child : mas-seraphin
 Theme URI:    http://www.mas-seraphin.com/wp-content/themes/mas-seraphin_responsive-child
 Description:  Responsive Child : mas -seraphin
 Author:       Emerik NICOLE
 Author URI:   http://www.e-nicole.info
 Template:     responsive
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  Responsive Child : mas-seraphin
*/



#mega-menu-wrap-header-menu {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #b06df4 !important;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b06df4), to(#b06df4)) !important;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b06df4, #b06df4) !important;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b06df4, #b06df4) !important;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b06df4, #b06df4) !important;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b06df4, #b06df4) !important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #b06df4, #b06df4) !important;

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#b06df4, endColorstr=#3d3d3d);
}

#wrapper {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 0px 20px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f2cb8a !important;
}
```

This is functions.php for the child theme

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
add_action('wp_footer','customized_js'); 


function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 
                    'parent-style',
                    get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', 
                    array() 
                    );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
                    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
                    array('parent-style')
                    );
}






if (!function_exists('customized_js')) {


    function customized_js(){
        echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."ter";
        echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/my-jquery-div-slide-effect.js';

        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 

        wp_register_script( 
                    'my-jquery-div-slide-effect',
                    get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/my-jquery-div-slide-effect.js',
                    array('jquery'),
                    '1.0',
                    True
                    );

        wp_enqueue_scripts('my-jquery-div-slide-effect');
    }
}


?>
```

I want to add a show/hide functionality on a div by clicking on a link of a wordpress page. So i load a custom js file my-jquery-div-slide-effect.js :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#tarifs').hide();
    jQuery('a#tarif_title').click(function() {
        jQuery('#tarifs').slideToggle(400);
        return false;
    });
});
```

When i look in firebug, it appears that my-jquery-div-slide-effect.js is not loaded whereas css overide just work well.

Can you point me what am i doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in your code:

```
wp_enqueue_scripts('my-jquery-div-slide-effect');
```

should be

```
wp_enqueue_script('my-jquery-div-slide-effect');
```